# Node email templates - Understanding file structure

Tags: node.js, directory

I have messed around with my directories and paths so much that I just posted the original from github

```
  var path           = require('path')
     , templatesDir   = path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'templates')
     , emailTemplates = require('../../')
     , nodemailer     = require('nodemailer');
```

If this is where I look for them. Can someone explain where I save my email templates? I am using the base express file structure so right inside my application file I have app.js, which holds this code. Thanks for anyone who knows. I am running out of things to try.

Comment: Have you tried templates directory in root?

Comment: yea. I gave up on it. I got to a point where I got an error code 34? which when I looked up gave me nothing